# lua logical operators / a?b:c operator

Tags: lua, ternary-operator

I don't understand the logic of

```
    aBoolValue = false
    ans = aBoolValue and 'yes' or 'no'
    print (ans)
```

What does the 'and' and 'or' operator exactly works?

Comment: Look up Lua short circuit evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html

For your example if aBoolValue == TRUE then it will print 'yes' else 'no'

Comment: I'd down vote this as a link-only answer but "the documentation is your friend" is always a good answer.

Comment: @Tom Blodget "lua and or" leads almost immediately  to that page, I'm pretty sure that the question should be downvoted, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
local example1 = true and "yes" or "no"
local example2 = false and "yes" or "no"

print(example1, example2) --> yes   no
```

If the boolean is true, the value after and will be returned.  If the boolean is false, the value after or will be returned.  Think of it like this:

```
local example1 = if (true) then "yes" else "no"
--obviously this code won't work, but it shows how ternary operations work
```